# Nominatim not match when using q parameter

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap, nominatim

I have the following issue.I want to use Nominatim to find coordinates from a textbox value i also add a select list with the country to make it easier to find.But the problem is :
When is i use the q parameter:

```
http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&q=Berlin&country=Germany
```

this gives me back some other Berlins which is in the Us for example.
But when i use the city parameter insted of q its works fine.

```
 http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&city=Berlin&country=Germany
```

But the problem is i can not 
use allways the city parameter because of the possibility of a town insted of city.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the [documentation](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim). You can't combine parameter *q* with any of the alternative search parameters. Instead you can give a more specific query string including the country:

> http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?format=json&q=Berlin,%20Germany

Comment: thank you for your comment!My porpuse would be to choose (in that case) only the main city of Germany i do not need to get other result.
But i dont know how to get match as precious as google geocoder.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "as precious as google geocoder" but you can just look at the `type` and `importance` attributes of the result.

Comment: i mean if i only want to get the main city of Germany(with the center point) i get several other results too

Comment: The search results are ordered by their importance. You can add `limit=1` to limit the search to one result if this is really bothering you.